# How to create a new(original) struts path?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, struts-1

I have tried overriding existing StrutsPortletAction before with their existing struts path with success. However, I can't seem to do the same if I were to try creating my own struts action path.

```
<hook>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/portal/set_viewers/</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.mine.blogs.hook.BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>
</hook>
```

The eclispe IDE gives me this error "/portal/set_viewers/" is not among possible values" and when I go ahead and deploy the built war anyways, tomcat errors as: `com.liferay.portal.kernal.util.InstanceFactory can not access a member of class com.mine.blogs.hook.BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction with modifiers ""`

Tried with struts-action-path as `/blogs/set_viewers/` failed as well.

This is the .java i'm using. Very basic actually.

```
package com.mine.blogs.hook;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletConfig;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.StrutsPortletAction;


public class BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction implements StrutsPortletAction {

BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void processAction(
    PortletConfig arg0, ActionRequest arg1, ActionResponse arg2)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("process1");

}

@Override
public void processAction(
    StrutsPortletAction arg0, PortletConfig arg1, ActionRequest arg2,
    ActionResponse arg3)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("process2");

}

@Override
public String render(
    PortletConfig arg0, RenderRequest arg1, RenderResponse arg2)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("render1");
    return null;
}

@Override
public String render(
    StrutsPortletAction arg0, PortletConfig arg1, RenderRequest arg2,
    RenderResponse arg3)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("render2");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void serveResource(
    PortletConfig arg0, ResourceRequest arg1, ResourceResponse arg2)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("serve1");

}

@Override
public void serveResource(
    StrutsPortletAction arg0, PortletConfig arg1, ResourceRequest arg2,
    ResourceResponse arg3)
    throws Exception {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("serve2");

}
}
```

And the corresponding liferay-hook.xml

```
<hook>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/blogs_entry/set_viewers/</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.mine.blogs.hook.BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>
</hook>
```

Comment: Are you extending your BlogEntryViewerStrutsPortletAction with BaseStrutsPortletAction ?

Comment: Yes have done that. But I also realized that the IDE did not prompt me to create the methods required for overriding such as render, processAction etc...

Comment: Its not mandatory to override all the methods, BaseStrutsPortletAction class has basic implementation of the methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was because of the Constructor. I've removed it and it's now deploying properly

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the struts action URL to something other than starting with "/portal". Liferay may be reserving "/portal" for portal level action paths.

For example,

```
        <struts-action-path>/blogs_entry/set_viewers/</struts-action-path>
```

Comment: I actually used '/blogs/set_viewers/'  at first before trying using /portal